# Inno Setup - Set Default Component depending on System Language

Tags: dynamic, inno-setup, pascal, multilingual

I'm relatively new to InnoSetup so excuse me if I'm missing something.

**Situation:** My program is organized into selectable components. "Core Component" and "Language Component" (and some other which are irrelevant here). The "Language Component" contains "English", "Spanish", and some more.. The setup is localized in all languages that the components support.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** When the user has for example a Spanish OS and selects the Spanish language for the setup, I want the "Language Component > Spanish" to be selected automatically BY DEFAULT, but the user still be able to select an other language for my programm even if the setup is in Spanish.

**What it does right now:** Right now the first language element is selected by default which is "English" as it is the first element. The user has to specifically select "Spanish" or other no matter what language is being used for the setup.

**Question:** Is it possible to make Inno Setup select or check components depending on the setup locale?

**Demo Code:**

```
[Setup]
AppName=My App
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\My App

[Components]
Name: "core_files"; Description: "Core Component"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "lang_files"; Description: "Language Component"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "lang_files\en"; Description: "English"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "lang_files\es"; Description: "Spanish"; Flags: exclusive;

[Files]
;Source: "Files\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: game_files
;Source: "Files_EN\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: lang_files\en
;Source: "Files_ES\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: lang_files\es

[Icons]  
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "es"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
```

**Please note:**
Using this does not seems to have any effect:

```
Name: "lang_files\es"; Description: "Spanish"; Languages: es; Flags: exclusive;
```

Using this is not an option for me, as the user cannot select an other language during installation, the only option for him would be changing the whole setup language if he wants to change my app language.

```
Source: "Files_ES\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Languages: es; Components: lang_files\es
```

**Conclusion:**
I hope there is some way to make this work. I was wondering why setting the language on the "Component" is being ignored or has just no effect but still does not show any errors while compiling. Maybe something like this would be possible in the [Code] section but I don't know anything about Pascal.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction is highly apreciated.
Greetings.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of at this time is accessing component items by index (and you can find the item only by its description). Nothing fancy, difficult to maintain. For your task it's essentially about getting the language by the `ActiveLanguage` and selecting the item e.g. by `WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[n] := True;` where `n` is the index of the component item of your choice. But then comes the funny part. You have no relationship between the `[Components]` entry and the `ComponentsList` item except the `Description` parameter. And what's worse, no relation to the language at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Hello everybody, thanks for the help. With a bit of google, brain and a lot of failed compiles I finally cold hack up some reasonably good looking solution.

Here is the code in case somebody would find it useful:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My App
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\My App

[Types]
Name: "full_en"; Description: "Full installation"; Languages: en; 
Name: "full_es"; Description: "Full installation"; Languages: es;
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom
; Full installation (With all languages)
#define full "full_en full_es"

[Components]
Name: "core_files"; Description: "Core Component"; Types: {#full} custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "lang_files"; Description: "Language Component"; Types: {#full} custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "lang_files\en"; Description: "English"; Types: full_en custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "lang_files\es"; Description: "Spanish"; Types: full_es custom; Flags: exclusive;

[Files]
;Source: "Files\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: game_files
;Source: "Files_EN\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: lang_files\en
;Source: "Files_ES\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: lang_files\es

[Icons]  
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "es"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
```

I'm using "Installation Types" to check the languages by default. This solution seems to work quite well for me right and works whichout mayor Pascal coding. As drawback is that it Requires per-language installation types, which can get quite big if you include many languages. I wonder if there is some other more elegand and compact way to do that.

Greetings and thanks for the help!

UPDATED: No pascal scripting involved at all now..
UPDATED 2: Using ISPP to avoid duplication, easier use and better readability using all languages for an element.

Comment: Well done! I'm afraid there isn't an elegant way. I could think of an external file with some known structure that would be parsed and inlined into the script by preprocessor. If you would e.g. store the `[Components]` section entries (only the language ones) as they are, like `Name: "lang_files\en"; Description: "English"; Flags: exclusive`, then you could get the language name and the `Description`; all what is needed to find a component (not reliably) and get a relation to the language. Preprocessor would just inline that into the section and do a short stuff in `[Code]`.

Comment: Would be storing the language specific component entries into an external file keeping the format like `Name: "lang_files\<lang>"` where `<lang>` would be the string returned by `ActiveLanguage` function acceptable for you ?

Comment: I guess that would be the perfect solution for it. Don't mind using external files. But I'm too weak with Pascal to hack such a code together.. Would it be possible for you to post an example code here? (TLama)

Answer (score 0):

From this page (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=languagessection) I read this information:

"If the ShowLanguageDialog [Setup] section directive is set to yes (the default), a Select Language dialog will be displayed which gives the user an opportunity to override the language Setup chose. On non Unicode Inno Setup languages that can't be displayed properly on the user's system will be hidden. See the [LangOptions] section help topic for details."

Comment: Yes, but this is not about showing the language dialog but pre-selecting a component according to the selected language. Except that the example script doesn't specify the `ShowLanguageDialog` directive, so it's in its default value.